# Error in saving matplotlib plot to tiff

Tags: python, matplotlib, tiff

I can successfully save a plot using matplotlib in .png format. However, when I try to save it in .tiff format, I get this error:

```
plt.savefig(base_dir+'Plots'+os.sep+path+os.sep+title+'.tiff',  dpi=500)
```

Error:

```
  File "C:/Users/r/workspace/FLE/plots.py", line 1310, in plot_by_region
    plt.savefig(base_dir+'Plots'+os.sep+path+os.sep+title+'.tiff',  dpi=500)
  File "C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 688, in savefig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1539, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 196, in print_figure
    FigureCanvasAgg.print_figure(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2230, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 594, in print_tif
    dpi=dpi)
  File "C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1665, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1320, in _save
    offset = ifd.save(fp)
  File "C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 608, in save
    if len(data) <= 4:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rolling back to Pillow 2.9.0 and saving to .tiff works. See here: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1524

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11078019)

Comment: @FabioLamanna, the essential parts of the answer are present in my answer.